# Homework help: Returning a value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a homework assignment where we have to make a simple calculator in JavaScript. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <style>
        div{
            display: inline-block;

        }
        #first{
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            top: 65px;
        }
        #fieldset{
            width: 70px;
        {
        #second{

        }   
        #compute{
            position: relative;
        {
    </style>

    <script>
        window.onload = function(){
            alert('Welcome to the JavaScript Calculator!');
        };

        function compute() {
            var firstValue = document.getElementById("first").value;
            var secondValue = document.getElementById("second").value;
            var output;
                if (document.getElementById("plus").checked === true)
                {
                    output = firstValue + secondValue;
                }
                else if (document.getElementById("minus").checked === true)
                {
                    output = firstValue - secondValue;
                }
                else if (document.getElementById("times").checked === true)
                {
                    output = firstValue*secondValue;
                }
                else if (document.getElementById("divide").checked === true)
                {
                    output = firstValue/secondValue;
                }
            return output;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Simple Calculator</h1>
    </header>

    <form>
        <div id="first">
            First value: <input type="text" name="FirstValue" />
        </div>
        <div id="fieldset">
        <fieldset id=radio>
                <label for="plus">+</label>
                <input type="radio" id="plus" name="type" value="plus" checked/><br>
                <label for="minus">-</label>
                <input type="radio" id="minus" name="type" value="minus"/><br>
                <label for="times">x</label> 
                <input type="radio" id="times" name="type" value="times"/><br>
                <label for="divide">&divide;</label>
                <input type="radio" id="divide" name="type" value="divide"/>
        </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div id="second">
            Second value: <input type="text" name="SecondValue" />
        </div>
        <div id="compute">
            <button type="button" onclick = "compute();">Compute</button>
        </div>
        Result:
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The calculator won't run, and I think that has something to do with how I've set it up to return. Does returning output print it to the screen? If not, how do I get this to happen? Please help! Thanks.

Comment: since it is home work I will give you hints.  compute() returns to where? It returns to no where. the onclick does not expect a return value. You need to update the result in code. Try ` Result: <span id="result"></span>` and replace the content from the compute() function

Answer (score 2):

There was a few things you needed to do.

1. You needed to get the value inserted into the textbox, not the value of the div.
2. You also needed to convert the input from a string to a number using `parseInt`.
3. Returning the output won't show it on the screen. Instead of returning the output, you needed to add it to the page as an answer by using `innerHTML`.

Run the code snippet below to see it in action.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <style>
        div{
            display: inline-block;

        }
        #first{
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            top: 65px;
        }
        #fieldset{
            width: 70px;
        {
        #second{

        }   
        #compute{
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        window.onload = function(){
            alert('Welcome to the JavaScript Calculator!');
        };

        function compute() {
            var firstValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstValue").value);

            var secondValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("secondValue").value);
            var output;
                if (document.getElementById("plus").checked === true)
                {
                    output = firstValue + secondValue;
                }
                else if (document.getElementById("minus").checked === true)
                {
                    output = firstValue - secondValue;
                }
                else if (document.getElementById("times").checked === true)
                {
                    output = firstValue*secondValue;
                }
                else if (document.getElementById("divide").checked === true)
                {
                    output = firstValue/secondValue;
                }

                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: " + output;
                return output;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Simple Calculator</h1>
    </header>

    <form>
        <div id="first">
            First value: <input id="firstValue" type="text" name="FirstValue" />
        </div>
        <div id="fieldset">
        <fieldset id=radio>
                <label for="plus">+</label>
                <input type="radio" id="plus" name="type" value="plus" checked/><br>
                <label for="minus">-</label>
                <input type="radio" id="minus" name="type" value="minus"/><br>
                <label for="times">x</label> 
                <input type="radio" id="times" name="type" value="times"/><br>
                <label for="divide">&divide;</label>
                <input type="radio" id="divide" name="type" value="divide"/>
        </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div id="second">
            Second value: <input id="secondValue" type="text" name="SecondValue" />
        </div>
        <div id="compute">
            <button type="button" onclick="compute();">Compute</button>
        </div>
        <div id="result">
        Result:
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```